# Logging in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, logging, laravel-5.5

I have a very simple question, I guest, but I can't find an answer to it in a documentation.

Here's how I log info now:

```
    $logger->debug('user_id: ', [Auth::id()]);
    $logger->debug('requested_url: ', [$request->getRequestUri()]);
    $logger->debug('requested_method: ', [$request->getMethod()]);
    $logger->debug('referer_url: ', [$request->headers->get('referer')]);
    $logger->debug('date_and_time: ', [Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString()]);
    $logger->debug('error_message: ', [$exception->getMessage()]);
    $logger->debug('http_status_code: ', [$this->prepareResponse($request, $exception)->getStatusCode()]);
    $logger->debug($exception->getMessage(), ['stack_trace' => $exception->getTraceAsString()]);
```

But I need to make it in a one line. I want see in the logs 1 message related to an error.

```
[2018-02-15 13:31:19] local.DEBUG: user_id:  [null]
[2018-02-15 13:31:19] local.DEBUG: requested_url:["/css/bootstrap.css.map"]
[2018-02-15 13:31:19] local.DEBUG: requested_method:  ["GET"]
[2018-02-15 13:31:19] local.DEBUG: referer_url:  [null]
[2018-02-15 13:31:19] local.DEBUG: date_and_time:  ["2018-02-15 13:31:19"]
[2018-02-15 13:31:19] local.DEBUG: error_message:  [""]
[2018-02-15 13:31:19] local.DEBUG: http_status_code:  [404]
[2018-02-15 13:31:19] local.DEBUG:  {"stack_trace":"#0 }
```

How can I manage it?

Comment: Add it all in one array of `debug([]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/logging#writing-log-messages):

> An array of contextual data may also be passed to the log methods. This contextual data will be formatted and displayed with the log message:

```
Log::info('User failed to login.', ['id' => $user->id]);
```

So, you could do this:

```
$logger->debug('The error message', [
    'user_id' => Auth::id(),
    'requested_url' => $request->getRequestUri(),
    ....
]);
```

Comment: You would probably need to use $logger->debug(print_r($array, true)) on that array with the second parameter set to true to return...